# Pdf corrupted in HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 project in which i am trying to download a pdf. I thought this would be pretty straightforward, but apparently not so, as the pdf somehow gets formatted wrongly when sent to the browser. Chrome will read the pdf, but all special characters and images looks corrupted, and Edge simply refuses to open it.

The pdf file is written in Danish, so it contains letters like 'æ', 'ø' and 'å', and also contains various images.

I've simplified my code current code, but the issue is still the same:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadDocument()
{
    try
    {
        var localFilePath = "C:\\*somepath*\\Testpdf.pdf";
        var fileStream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
        response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"Testpdf.pdf\"");
        response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", fileStream.Length.ToString());
        response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Name", "Testpdf.PDF");
        response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf;charset=UTF-8");
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

It reads a pdf from the disk and assigns the filestream to the content of the HttpResponseMessage. In the example I'm using a StreamContent, but the result is still the same if switch to ByteArrayContent.

I've also tried writing the file back onto the disk, with no issues at all. I've litterally just done the same behaviour in a dotnetcore 2.0 web project, with no issues what-so-ever, which leads me to believe that the formatters in of the Web API is parsing the content wrong.

I'm at my wits end here, so any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you set the content-type to `application/pdf;charset=UTF-8`? Are you certain that's the character set used in the PDF?

Comment: I used this line to check it:
    var e = new StreamReader(fileStream).CurrentEncoding;
which gives "Unicode (UTF-8)".

Only writing application/pdf yields the same result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by removing the jwt "Authorization" token from the Request Headers. I changed it to get the token from the url instead, by making a alternate provider, following this article:
https://leastprivilege.com/2013/10/31/retrieving-bearer-tokens-from-alternative-locations-in-katanaowin/

Comment: How is this answer related to your original question?